# Bolt pattern equivalency reference

Tags: wheels

I'm shopping for a set of used wheels. Most sellers don't know the bolt hole measurements and just say the number of holes and the vehicle they came from, "5 bolt for Jeep Cherokee/Tacoma/Nissan/..."

Is there a Web calculator or chart somewhere that lists vehicle bolt pattern equivalents, arranged by Make and Model?

Failing that, can anyone tell me what vehicles match Dodge Journey (2009)? E.g. *"rims from Nissan Rogue and ... and ... will fit on Dodge Journey and ..."*

OEM is 5 bolt x 127mm centres, 6-7"wide, 35-44mm offset.

Comment: When you say "equivalents" are you looking for an inch measurement, or what exactly?

Comment: @paulster I'm looking for _"rims from Nissan Rogue and ... and ... will fit on Dodge Journey and ..."_. Q updated accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term you are looking for is 'PCD' or pitch circle diameter. Take a look at this website, it lists your car along with almost every other!

[wheelfitment.eu](http://www.wheelfitment.eu/car/Dodge/Journey%20(2008%20-%20).html)

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. After using site for a bit I've determined best useability is to find your own vehicle's PCD then use "Search by PCD" (and centre bore) feature instead of Search by Make. This way you get list of matching model years as well in one list: http://www.wheelfitment.eu/PCD/5x127/71.6.html