# wheel compatabily for 7J 17 ET50

Tags: wheels, compatibility

any idea ...there is a chart out there that gives all vehicles that use this size wheel....I have a nissan Sentra SE R..want to go to salvage to get steel rims so need a list of compatible vehicles that use these same size wheels

Answer (score 0):

For decades "The Hollander Interchange Manual" has been the bible for salvaged auto parts. It has two sections, the first section designates a unique Hollander part number for a specific part. The second section lists all the vehicles that use the same part number. They are now available electronically, they are not inexpensive. Most reputable recycle centers will inform you what models and years you can use if you are picking your own parts.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in in Sam's answer in this thread [Bolt pattern equivalency reference](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/22004/bolt-pattern-equivalency-reference?rq=1), you can use a clumsier (but less expensive!) alternative by looking up individual wheels on [Wheelfitment.eu](https://www.wheelfitment.eu/index.php)